# Why do I always run into EOF error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why do I always run into EOF error even with the simplest input. I tried this code and it returned EOF error:

```
var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
print "you entered", var
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried it in several online IDE like codechef and IDEone and it always gives back the same EOF error...

Comment: It's running perfectly on my system. What did you enter as input? What OS are you using?

Comment: I tried it in several online IDE's and every one of them just gives the same error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: That's very strange. Could you share the link of your uploads? It's working fine on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/nPiZ6y).

Comment: https://ideone.com/iPAUcL

Comment: It's giving the error because you didn't enter any input. See my link; I have entered "hello" as stdin. You have left it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Standard input is empty
```

On ideone, you have to provide input before you run your program.

If you want to run your program interactively, look for another online interpreter ([repl.it](http://repl.it) does that).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I had to put the input before running the code